# How to assign the textview value in to the button?

Tags: javascript, android

I have a function which is actually set the name into the text view, and I have a button listener which is actually defined inside the `oncreate` method. All the names have a unique object id. I need to get the object id of the selected name into the `onclick` function of the button and this object id is passing in the intent through bundle extras to the next activity. The function is defined outside the `oncreate` method. All the names and corresponding ids are coming through the web service call.

The function which sets the text view is

```java
public void setMarker(){

  mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

      SaloonDetails = "";
      // Take some action here
      String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
      objectId = snippet;

      if (selectedMarker != null && !("currentLocation".equals(snippet))) {
        selectedMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.map_red));
      }

      selectedMarker = marker;
      if (!("currentLocation".equals(snippet)))
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.map_blue));

      Log.i("TAG", "snippet::::" + snippet);

      if ("currentLocation".equals(snippet)) {
        selectedLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //button_bookmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return false;
      } else {

        selectedLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        TextView nameView = ((TextView) selectedLayout
          .findViewById(R.id.name_txt_id));

        TextView addressView = ((TextView) selectedLayout
          .findViewById(R.id.address_txt_id));

        Button button = ((Button) selectedLayout
          .findViewById(R.id.selec_button_id));

        try {
          JSONObject jSalonData = (JSONObject)SalonData.get(snippet);

          nameView.setText(jSalonData.getString("SalonName"));

          // button.setText(jSalonData.getString("SalonName"));
          String  Slecteditem1= nameView.getText().toString();

          Log.i("Sltitem olemapsAivity",Slecteditem1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
          JSONObject jSalonData = (JSONObject)SalonData.get(snippet);
          Log.i("jSalonData",jSalonData.toString());

          City = jSalonData.optString("City");
          SaloonDetails = SaloonDetails + City;
          Zipcode = jSalonData.optString("Zipcode");
          SaloonDetails = SaloonDetails  +" "+ Zipcode;
          HouseNumber = jSalonData.optString("HouseNumber");
          SaloonDetails = SaloonDetails  +" "+ HouseNumber;
          Street = jSalonData.optString("Street");
          SaloonDetails = SaloonDetails +" "+ Street;
          Log.i("SaloonDetails", SaloonDetails);
          addressView.setText(SaloonDetails);

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
      }
    }

  });
}
```

The `onclick` function of the button is

```java
Button button = ((Button)         

selectedLayout.findViewById(R.id.selec_button_id));

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    // On click function
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        Button b = (Button)view;
        String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
        Log.i("buttonText",buttonText);
        //String Slecteditem = hm.get(buttonText);

        //Log.i("objectidddddd",Slecteditem);

        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Salon_Detail.class);
        //extras.putString("Slecteditem", Slecteditem);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: please http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTag/getTag` method of Button to get text according to clicked Button as:

**1.** Call setTag method by passing `Slecteditem1` String:

```
  String  Slecteditem1= nameView.getText().toString();
  button.setTag(Slecteditem1);
```

**2.** In `onClick` method get selected text from Button using getTag().

```
 ...
 Bundle extras = new Bundle();
 extras.putString("Slecteditem", view.getTag().toString());
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: How can i get the id corresponding to the selected name . it is available only in the setmarker function.How to pass both ?

Comment: @Maria: Maria  always changing question focus. if you want other items from setmarker method then instead of using `Slecteditem1 ` in `setTag ` like `button.setTag(jSalonData.toString());` and parse jsonobject inside onClick method to get other values